# Any change to the 'Script Execution Order' is immediately reverted

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the weirdest bug. If I edit anything in the 'Script Execution Order' list in Project Settings, and click 'Apply', it just reverts back to how it was before immediately. This includes any type of change: removal of entries, adding entries, or changing the number of the entry. Everything just plops right back to the previous state on clicking Apply - no error messages whatsoever.

Visually, it's exactly the same result as clicking the 'Revert' button instead of 'Apply' - except that the editor actually starts doing its refresh thing afterwards (I thought for a moment maybe the Apply button was broken, but this kinda rules that out).

After hours of trying stuff I figured out that it works if I remove the 'Unity UI' package, so I guess the problem may have to do something with that. However, another project that includes this package does not have the same problem.. so it's still project-related, somehow. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling all packages 10 times, no luck..

Comment: there is nothing to do for you if it's a software bug
contact support and report a bug, also I recommend updating Unity software

Comment: Thank you; I've updated to the latest (stable) version to no avail. I've reported this as a bug to Unity.

Comment: Looks like your/plugin script is forcing 'Script Execution Order' via very bad practices, it's less likely that this is a bug but probable nontheless

Comment: Sounds like this is done by one of the packages or other assets you added?

Comment: It's a new project with no external assets whatsoever, just 3 .png files and 4 self-made scripts of a few lines long, that do only some physics things, nothing fancy. The only packages included are ones that come with Unity. Very strange!

Comment: @derHugo, I may have misunderstood you. It was indeed the packages' entries themselves which were readonly - user entries aren't (I had assumed they would be; that there'd be no difference between packages' and my own entries, and the whole list was readonly). So in other words, the problem was not caused by a package, but it was local to the package, which made it a non-problem :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had submitted this as a bug to Unity support, who have just responded.

> After some investigation, I've concluded that this is currently by
> design. You're trying to make changes to scripts from Packages,
> currently, you can't do that. If you would add your own script and try
> to change the execution order, you'd notice that everything works
> correctly. (Matas, Customer QA Team)

He is correct, and indeed, changing/adding entries from your own code DOES work. In hindsight, this makes sense, even if it's a bit rigid. Problem 'solved', as in, I can live with packages' entries being readonly.